# VUEJS - How to write var test = new Vue() inside export method

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2

VUEJS - How to write 
**var test = new Vue()** 
inside export method

Answer (score 0):

There are two ways you can achive this.

```
let test = new Vue()
export { test as default}

export let test = new Vue()
```